# Is there a way to see all the references of a method in netbeans similar to the newer version of visual studio

Tags: java, netbeans

I was using a fresh installed visual studio when i noticed you can now quickly see the reference above the methods. I was wondering if there is a similar way to do this in netbeans ? Because sometimes when i refactor my code i'm losing a lot of time searching where all the references are .

Comment: Do you mean "find usages"? (right-click on the method / variable / etc.)

Comment: @JoachimRohde make that an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the cursor on any method / variable / etc. and press [left Alt]+[F7] or just right-click on it and select "Find usages".

Comment: Great this wil speed up things ;)

Comment: "Find Usages" is Alt+F7 in NetBeans 11.

Answer (score -2):

Netbeans 11 not support "Find usages" for js code :(

Comment: This is not a helpful answer to the original question.